# Google Play Console: The SDK developer androidx.fragment has reported fragment:1.0.0 as outdated- Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-fragments, google-play, google-play-console, androidx

I have started getting this warning on Google Play Store for a Unity project.

> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Consider upgrading to a newer version (1.1.0+).

However, I am having trouble figuring out where I am using this in the project.

Any ideas?

I have searched the project for this plugin but can't find it.

Comment: Have you tried updating the SDK.

Comment: I can't find where I am using it or where it is located in the project.

Comment: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 is a dependency of Play Services Basement library (the latest version still depends on v1.0.0). Many Google library use Play Services Basement library (Google Play Services libraries, Firebase libraries, AdMob). See: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/18.2.0

Comment: I use Jetpack Compose and don't use any fragment or any dependency related to the `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0`, but still getting that issue shown in Google Play Console. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find all dependencies your project has in android studio
Build your app for android with "Export project" checked in build settings ([Unity build settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZWqH.png))

Open the result project in android studio, go to View > Tool Windows > Gradle, select the "launcher" and click Analyze Dependencies button in the top panel of the view, from there you can search the whole dependency tree ([Android Studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbonp.png))

For me it is AppLovin adapter that still has this dependency

Comment: How do you select the "launcher", I don't see this ? I have the name of my project instead of "launcher".

Answer (score 3):

You can find the library using a particular dependency using the following steps (refer to the image).

1. click on the gradle side tab.
2. click on the magnifying glass (dependency analyzer)
3. search for the dependency of interest.
4. the usages will be displayed as a list.

[image]

Comment: in 2nd step Mgnified glass is not shown : Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJFNm.png)Go to the build.gradle section of your app  and in the dependecies section paste this that i have put in brackets here(   constraints.implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6') and android studio will download what is required to solve your problem ,then sync your project and generate your signed apk or app bundle and that outdated fragment error in your google play store should dissapear

Comment: can you please tell us how to make it in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using **constraints** to update transitive dependencies in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    constraints{
        implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.2"){
            because("Gms library depends on outdated androidx fragment")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see attached image where you can find the SDK so you can manually change.  [image]

Additionally sometimes some cluster files may cause it so see the attached image. You may wanna backup your project and when Unity is not working delete this files and then start Unity [image: image2]